# Asymptotic behaviour of Lambert series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

How can I examine asymptotic behaviour of Lambert series $f(x) = \sum_{}^{} \frac{x^{n}}{1-x^{n}}$ when $x$ approaches $1^{-}$- for instance find function $ g(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = const$. I would really appreciate some hints or referalls to any similiar examples since I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01085.pdf
the sum you are looking for is $\mathcal{L}_{q}(0,1)$ in their notation

Answer (score 5):

An elementary approach is to note that the map $t \mapsto \frac{x^t}{1-x^t}$ is decreasing for $0 < x < 1$, so

$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{x^t}{1-x^t}\,dt \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{1-x^n} \leq \frac{x}{1-x} + \int_1^\infty \frac{x^t}{1-x^t}\,dt.
$$

Since

$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{x^t}{1-x^t}\,dt = \frac{\log(1-x)}{\log x} \sim \frac{\log(1-x)}{x-1}
$$

as $x \nearrow 1$, we conclude that

$$
\lim_{x \nearrow 1} \frac{x-1}{\log(1-x)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{1-x^n} = 1.
$$

Answer (score 4):

We can find an asymptotic formula using the residue theorem and the inverse Mellin transform : $$\begin{array}{ll}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n) e^{-nx} &=& \displaystyle\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} \Gamma(s) \zeta(s)^2 x^{-s} ds\\ &=& Res(\Gamma(s) \zeta(s)^2 x^{-s},1)+Res(\Gamma(s) \zeta(s)^2 x^{-s},0) +Res(\Gamma(s) \zeta(s)^2 x^{-s},-1) \\ && \qquad \qquad\displaystyle +\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{-3/2-i\infty}^{-3/2+i\infty} \Gamma(s) \zeta(s)^2 x^{-s} ds\\ &=& \displaystyle \frac{A\ln x+B}{x} +C+ \mathcal{O}(x) \qquad\qquad (x\to 0^+,\sigma > 1)\end{array}$$

Where $$Res(\Gamma(s) \zeta(s)^2 x^{-s},1)=Res((1-\gamma (s-1))(\frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma)^2 x^{-s},1)= \frac{-\ln x+\gamma}{x}$$ and $$Res(\Gamma(s) \zeta(s)^2 x^{-s},0) = Res(\frac{\zeta(0)^2}{s},0) = \frac{1}{4}$$
Therefore
$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{y^n}{1-y^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n) y^n = \frac{-\ln (-\ln y)+\gamma}{-\ln y} +\frac{1}{4}+ \mathcal{O}(\ln y) \qquad\qquad (y \to 1^-)}$$

Comment: [WA confirms my residues](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Res%5BGamma%5Bs%5D+Zeta%5Bs%5D%5E2+x%5E(-s),+%7Bs,1%7D%5D) are correct

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$$

Note that when $|x^n| < 1$,
$$ \frac{x^n}{1-x^n} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{kn}$$
so $f(x)$ becomes
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{kn}  = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \tau(j) x^j$$
where $\tau(j)$ is the number of divisors of $j$.

Comment: Using elementary arguments it can then be shown that since $\sum_{j=1}^{n} \tau(j) \sim n \log n$ we have $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \tau(j) x^j \sim \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (\log j) x^j \sim \int_0^\infty (\log t) x^t\,dt = \frac{\log(-\log x) + \gamma}{\log x} \sim \frac{\log(1-x)}{x-1}$$ as $x \nearrow 1$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas $-\gamma$ ?

Comment: @user1952009, this only gives the leading order term, so the $+\gamma$ (which is correct there) doesn't matter.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Well see my derivation below, I get $\frac{\gamma}{-\ln x}$ as the second term

Comment: @user1952009, I saw and upvoted :)

Comment: What is not obvious at first is that minus those terms $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n) e^{-nx}$ is analytic at $x=0$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57500/discussion-between-antonio-vargas-and-user1952009).